# syntax error using Last_insert_id()

Tags: mysql, sql

i am trying to an insert statement using last_insert_id() , i want to take the last inserted ID and insert it as a foreign key in an another table.

this is the statement :

```
String stt= "insert into Takes_lesson values (lid,sid) (LAST_INSERT_ID(),"+sid+");";
```

yet a syntax error occurs , what seems to be the problem? 
thanks in advance

Comment: What error message did you receive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Keyword/operands in the wrong order..

The column specification should be before the `VALUES` keyword when doing an `INSERT`, compare your query to the below:

```
INSERT INTO Takes_lesson (lid,sid) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), ... )
```

Comment: @MarwanTushyeh please remember to vote-up, accept the answer when you are able to. Thank you, glad it all worked out!